# asp.net core 3 Web Api ! send json to POST Action

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Hello (first sorry for my english)
i created a api for my project.
it work in local host when i send data in json format to my server.
but when i published it to host ! it dose not working !
action should accept every request from anyone.(post action)
action will receive JsIssueViewModel (my class with the same prop with json values)
[this is my action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRexg.jpg)

and this is my res of send data to my api (api in host , in localhost it's working) :
[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJjVo.jpg)

it return 404 code ! but this is working in localhost

Edit: Screenshots of startup.cs [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDWaJ.jpg) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR4lZ.jpg)

Comment: that was for my domain SSL .

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshots, the endpoint you're trying to hit is 'http://api.microprosoft.ir/jsissue/newIssue'.

However, the action method on the controller has no [HttpPost] attribute and hence the 404 (Not Found) error code. There is no matching action method that is found for the POST HTTP verb.

Add the [HttpPost] attribute on your action method or follow the route based convention and trigger like this - 'http://api.microprosoft.ir/jsissue/newJsIssue' (for this, you  have to enable the Route attribute)

Comment: thank you for your answer . HttpPost Attr was enabled and i deleted it for test ! when it was enable the result was same as the this ( 404 code ) . when i change url to my localhost (my xhr req url): http://localhost:60853/jsissue/newIssue , it will work

Comment: Are you sure your configuration is appropriate inside of Startup.cs? Further, are you hosting the entire folder or just the API project alone independently? Also, check if there are any errors logged on the server against the application.

Comment: i will send my startup file screen shots ! see them please